# Plotting iterated functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

As explained to me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45678/creating-cobweb-diagrams-of-some-functions-with-tikz-pstrick-etc), one can plot iterations of a point "b" in A under the functions f:A -> A. Is it also possible to plot the entire function iterated, meaning given a function "f", is it possible to plot f composed with f; or f composed m times with itself ?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of [your earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45678/creating-cobweb-diagrams-of-some-functions-with-tikz-pstrick-etc), you should show what you have tried so far, preferably as a a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly the question but a possibility  is below. I give you two different ways but for  f composed m times with itself I think it's not possible. Perhaps a TeX's wizard can find a solution but I'm very sceptic. Perhaps you can provide further informations so that we can give you a better solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ arrows, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10,
                    declare function={f(\t)=(exp(\t)-1)/(exp(1)-1);},
                    declare function={f2(\t)=f(f(\t)));},
                    declare function={f3(\t)=f(f(f(\t))));}]
  \draw [help lines,step=.2] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw [blue, 
         thick]
            plot [domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{f(\x)}); 
   \draw [red, 
          thick]
            plot [domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{f2(\x)});
   \draw [green, 
          thick]
            plot [domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{f3(\x)});  
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10,
                    declare function={f(\t)=(exp(\t)-1)/(exp(1)-1);},
                    declare function={g(\t,\n)= equal(2,\n) ? f(f(\t)) : f(f(f(\t)));}
                    ]
  \draw [help lines,step=.2] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw [blue, 
         thick]
            plot [domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{f(\x)}); 
   \draw [red, 
          thick]
            plot [domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{g(\x,2)});
   \draw [green, 
          thick]
            plot [domain=0:1, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{g(\x,3)});   
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Function involutive fof =Id

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
                    declare function={f(\t)=1/(\t-1)+1;},
                    declare function={f2(\t)=f(f(\t)));}]
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (5.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,5.2) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw [blue, 
         thick]
            plot [domain=1.3:5, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{f(\x)}); 
   \draw [red, 
          thick]
            plot [domain=1.3:5, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{f2(\x)}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]