# How to draw a cobweb graph like this one?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How to draw a cobweb graph like this one with tikz?
[image]

Reading other topics, this is what i got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\newcounter{j} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=10,
     declare function={%
         p(\t)=  greater(\t,0.5)  ? 1 :  2* \t ;}]  
    \draw[color=blue,domain=-0:1.05] plot (\x,{\x^3});    
    \draw[color=green](0,0)--(1.1,1.1);
    \draw[->](0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[->](0,0)--(1,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \newcommand{\x}{.1}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}{%
       \pgfmathparse{(p(\x)}
       \let\y\pgfmathresult
       \draw[color=magenta](\x,\x)--(\x,\y)--(\y,\y);
       \draw[color=orange,dotted,line width=0.8pt]%
            (\x,\x)--(\x,0) node[below=8pt]{$u_\i$};
       \pgfmathsetcounter{j}{\i+1}
       \draw[color=blue,dotted,line width=0.8pt]%
            (\x,\y)--(0,\y) node[left=8pt] {$u_\thej$};
       \global\let\x\y}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to change the `p` function to the cubic one: `p(\t) = \t^3`. Also, change the initial point to `\newcommand{\x}{.75}`.

Comment: a reference for cobweb diagrams https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45701/140722

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an outline to get you started. The idea is to define (declare) a function `f(\x)`. After the function and line are plotted, we use `\foreach` to perform a set number of iterations. Use `\evaluate` in the for loop to calculate `\newv`, the value of the function at the start value `\startv`. Then draw vertically to the function and horizontally to the line using `\draw (\startv,\startv)|-(\newv,\newv);`. Finally reset the value of `\startv` to the calculated value `\newv` and loop.

[image]

The code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\startv}{.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x*\x;}]
\draw[<->](0,1.1)|-(1.1,0);
\draw[green!70!black] (0,0)--(1,1);
\draw[blue, domain=0:1, smooth] plot (\x,{f(\x)});
\foreach \t[evaluate=\t as \newv using f(\startv)] in {1,...,4}{
    \draw[red] (\startv,\startv)|-(\newv,\newv);
    \xdef\startv{\newv}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can easily change the function, start value, and number of iterations.

For example: Set `f(\x)=3.2*\x*(1-\x);`. Change `\newcommand{\startv}{.25}`, and loop 100 times with `{1,...,100}` to produce the image

[image]

Similarly, `f(\x)=3.8*\x*(1-\x);` gives us

[image]

You could put the whole thing into a macro called `\cobweb` with three arguments (one optional):

`\cobweb[<start value>]{<function>}{<iterations>}`

`<start value>` is optional (default=.5), `<function>` must use `\x` for the variable. Sample use:

```
\cobweb[.8]{\x*\x*\x}{4}\qquad
\cobweb[.25]{3.2*\x*(1-\x)}{100}\qquad
\cobweb{3.8*\x*(1-\x)}{100}
```

produces

[image]

Here is the code with the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\cobweb}[3][.5]{% \cobweb[<start value>]{<function>}{<iterations>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,declare function={f(\x)=#2;}]
    \xdef\startv{#1}
    \draw[<->](0,1.1)|-(1.1,0);
    \draw[green!70!black] (0,0)--(1,1);
    \draw[blue, domain=0:1, smooth] plot (\x,{f(\x)});
    \foreach \t[evaluate=\t as \newv using f(\startv)] in {1,...,#3}{
    \draw[red] (\startv,\startv)|-(\newv,\newv);
    \xdef\startv{\newv}}
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\cobweb[.8]{\x*\x*\x}{4}\qquad
\cobweb[.25]{3.2*\x*(1-\x)}{100}\qquad
\cobweb{3.8*\x*(1-\x)}{100}

\end{document}
```

### Update:

I decided to keep playing with this to examine the bifurcating and chaotic behavior found by iterating the family of functions f(x)=4λx(1-x). That function is now built in to a macro `\bifur` that takes 4 arguments, one optional:

`\bifur[<skip>]{<start value>}{<lambda>}{<iterations>}`

The optional argument `<skip>` will not plot the first `<skip>` iterations of the function to see the long-term behavior. If omitted, no iterations will be skipped. For example, to skip the first 50 iterations and draw the next 100 (and compare with skip=0):

```
\bifur{.1}{.8}{100}\qquad
\bifur[50]{.1}{.8}{100}

\bifur{.1}{.88}{100}\qquad
\bifur[50]{.1}{.88}{100}

\bifur{.1}{.96}{100}\qquad
\bifur[50]{.1}{.96}{100}

\bifur{.1}{.97}{100}\qquad
\bifur[50]{.1}{.97}{100}
```

[image]

Here is the code with the `\bifur` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\tikzset{tick/.style={draw, minimum width=0pt, minimum height=2pt, inner sep=0pt, label=below:$\scriptstyle#1$},
    tick/.default={}}

\newcommand{\bifur}[4][0]{% \bifur[<skip>]{<start value>}{<lambda>}{<iterations>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,declare function={f(\x)=#3*4*\x*(1-\x);}]
    \draw[<->](0,1.1)|-(1.1,0);
    \node[tick=1] at (1,0){}; \node[tick=#3,rotate=-90] at (0,#3){};
    \xdef\startv{#2}
    \draw[green!70!black] (0,0)--(1,1);
    \draw[blue, domain=0:1, smooth] plot (\x,{f(\x)});
    \ifthenelse{#1=0}{}{
    \foreach \t[evaluate=\t as \newv using f(\startv)] in {1,...,#1}{
    \xdef\startv{\newv}}}
    \foreach \t[evaluate=\t as \newv using f(\startv)] in {1,...,#4}{
    \draw[red, very thin, line cap=round, line join=round] (\startv,\startv)|-(\newv,\newv);
    \xdef\startv{\newv}}
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\bifur{.1}{.8}{100}\qquad
\bifur[50]{.1}{.8}{100}

\end{document}
```

Here is is turned into a gif:

[image]

Comment: What an excellent answer!

Comment: Wow! Incredible. What is the next step? An animation? A control bar for the parameter? I never thought someone could do this in TikZ. You are fantastic. =]

Comment: @FHZ: Thank you. Yes, I'm planning an animation. Soon.

Comment: Impressive! Congratulations.

Comment: Very impressive... and so simply put. You're killing it!

Comment: @FHZ: Added the animation if you're interested.

Comment: @SebGlav: Thank you! I added an animation.

Comment: @SandyG, your work is awesome, but I could not reproduce the animation. I know about the package `animate`, but you don't seem to using it. How did you create the animation on the PDF (assuming here the PDF is animated).

Comment: @FHZ: The gif was made on (https://ezgif.com/). I created the document using `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` using the code `\begin{document} \foreach \l in {0,.01,...,1.005}{\pgfmathroundto{\l}\xdef\xx{\pgfmathresult}\bifur[50]{.11}{\xx}{100}}`, which makes a 100-page pdf that ezgif.com converts easily. Looking around, there doesn't seem to be much information about this kind of construction. Maybe I'll post a question with this solution.

Answer (score 6):

I translate [TikZ code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640044/140722) of @Sandy G to [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

[image]

```
// COBWEB
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
// Asymptote translation from Sandy G at
// https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640044/140722
unitsize(5cm);
import graph;
real f(real x){return 3.8*x*(1-x);}
path gf=graph(f,0,1);
draw((1.1,0)--(0,0)--(0,1.1),Arrows(TeXHead));
draw((0,0)--(1,1),.7green);
draw(gf,blue);

real startv=.5;
int n=50;
for(int i=1; i<n; ++i){
real newv=f(startv);
draw((startv,startv)--(startv,newv)--(newv,newv),red);  
startv=newv;
}
  
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```